# Adding steps, breadcrumbs, or navigation to multistep webform

Tags: webforms, navigation

I have a multi-step webform (about 10 pages), and I want the user to simply be able to skip ahead of their current location *if* they have had more progress previously.

I've been trying to use the Webform Steps module, but it's totally inaccurate and it shows the same button name for every form i.e. Step 1, Step 1, Step 1, not Step 1, 2, 3 etc. There's no customisation options for it, and I'm not comfortable with hacking it.

I've tried a couple other Modules, and they have similar behaviour, or they cannot actually link to other pages, as in the anchor tag is empty.

Is there a Module capable of doing this? Or do I need to do it myself? I'm relatively new to Drupal, and my PHP isn't *that* strong.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: sounds like it could be a bug in the module - you may get a better response by creating an item in the issue queue for that module

Comment: Yeah I will definitely do this too, but I figured I can get a much faster response here. And I figured others may have alternatives to the module I'm currently using.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform_steps?status=All&categories=All) of the [Webform steps](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_steps) module.

> webform_steps-7.x-1.x is the currently stable version. It works with **webform-7.x-3.x** only.

Webform steps module doesn't work well with Webform 7.x-4.x version. see the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2279595)

If you're using webform-7.x-3.x version. Here are the steps to make it work.

Webform steps module uses *pagebreak* labels as Step labels. So go to your form webform settings and change the *pagebreak* labels as you want to use as steps

For example if you want to use label steps as Step-1, Step-2 .. Step-10. Change the page break labels like Step-1... Step-10